# sorting python list according to given texts

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
l = ['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_4.png', 'fig_2.png']
```

Expected after sort:

```
result = ['fig_1.png', 'fig_2.png', 'fig_4.png', 'fig_10.png']
```

I tried as:

result = sorted(l)

But,

`['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_2.png', 'fig_4.png']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print `l.sort()` as it is in place sorting.

Use

```
l = ['fig_1.png', 'fig_3.png', 'fig_4.png', 'fig_2.png']
l.sort() #this will print none as it is in place and does not return anything
print l
```

Output:`['fig_1.png', 'fig_2.png', 'fig_3.png', 'fig_4.png']`

```
import re
l = ['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_4.png', 'fig_2.png']
l.sort(key=lambda x:int(re.findall(r"(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)",x)[0]))
print l
```

Comment: Not working in this case `l = ['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_4.png', 'fig_2.png']`

Comment: How to do it using the information from `os.path.basename(f).split('_')[1][:-4]`

Comment: actually i do not want to use `re` due to too much ....

Comment: `['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_2.png', 'fig_4.png']`

Comment: @usagi you can use `l.sort(key=lambda m: int(m.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]))`

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
result = sorted(l)
```

It'll work.

Comment: What error it's giving ?

Comment: the result is not sorting1

Comment: Not working in this case `l = ['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_4.png', 'fig_2.png']`

Comment: What output are you getting ?

Comment: `['fig_1.png', 'fig_10.png', 'fig_2.png', 'fig_4.png']`

Comment: Oh I see, It's actually sorting according to ascii values of chars in string.